# Do we have different badges in different SE sites

Tags: support, badges

Do we have different set of badges in different SE sites. eg. I don't see any 'Pundit' badge in badges popup in Hinduism SE.

Also, if the above is true, then can we include the left badges in a SE site at a later stage.

Answer (score 9):

> Do we have different set of badges in different SE sites

There is a base set of badges - this is common to all sites (go to `/help/badges` on any site - these are them). 'Pundit' is one of these badges. You will see it on the list, though it does not appear to have been awarded to anyone yet on Hinduism.

Additionally, there are tag badges - badges given for participation in tags. These depend on what tags exist on each site and the amount of participation in each tag. The set of these would be different on each site.

Comment: You might also want to add that some general badges' availability depends on other per-site factors (like tags). *Generalist* would be the first example (and maybe the only one?).

Comment: @Oded I see Pundit it in the list but when I open the badges POPUP from the User profile window, I am not able to see that badge. In the popup I can see all the badges whether I am progressing on a batch or not. I cannot see this badge in both Hinduism SE as well as Meta SE from user profile screen. Is it a bug ?

Comment: That is by design. Some of the badges are not trackable, as tracking them would cause too much strain on our databases.